# Is it possible to map 1:1 port range iptable DNAT rules

Tags: iptables, nat

I want the following rules to forward tcp packets 
from `127.0.0.1:32770` to `172.17.0.36:1000`
and forward packets from `127.0.0.1:32771` to `172.17.0.36:10001`
and forward packets from `127.0.0.1:32772` to `172.17.0.36:10002`

```
iptables -t nat -A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 32770:32771 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.36:1000-1002
```

But currently it can forward all packets from `127.0.0.1:32770-32771` to any one of `172.17.0.36:1000-1002`

Comment: If you want an exact 1:1 mapping, try splitting your rule to three different rules.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I need thousands of ports per docker container. It'll be very slow to start up the container.

Answer (score 5):

I've struggled a lot to find this and finally found a solution that absolutely works, the command in your case would be:

```
iptables -t nat -A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 32770:32771 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.36:1000-1002/32770
```

Here, 32770 is the base-port, and the mapping will start from there, for example:

```
32770 -> 172.17.0.36:1000
32771 -> 172.17.0.36:1001
```

Now, let's say the incoming range and outgoing range are not equal:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 30000:30199 -j DNAT --to 10.1.1.1:40000-40099/30000
```

In the above case, the DNAT mapping will round itself like this:

```
30000 -> 10.1.1.1:40000
30001 -> 10.1.1.1:40001
...
30099 -> 10.1.1.1:40099
30100 -> 10.1.1.1:40000
30101 -> 10.1.1.1:40001
...
30199 -> 10.1.1.1:40099
```

The support for base-port based 1:1 port mapping in DNAT was added in 2018.
Please refer below link:
http://git.netfilter.org/iptables/commit/?id=36976c4b54061b0147d56892ac9d402dae3069df

I have seen this working in Linux kernel 4.19 and above.

Comment: Oh god thanks, you saved me from madness!